# Weird thing --onclick event disappears when I switch the visual and text tab

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onclick

here is the piece of code I want to add the wordpress page: 
[image]
But when I click visual tab and come back to text tab. The onclick event disappeared:
[image]
[image]

**Can anyone explain why it happens? why do it change the code when I switch the visual and text tab! Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I'm guessing the text editor doesn't allow JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this question:

[Wordpress insert javascript into page text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370950/wordpress-insert-javascript-into-page-text-area)

Basically, check that you are not inside a p or anther element or have a look to the plugin they suggest on that answer:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress strips code from your posts which is why that is happening.

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/placing-javascript-in-posts