# Wordpress page editor bug?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm building a page in wordpress editor and I need to add this piece of code

```
<input style="width: 10%; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #757575;" type="text" value="1" onchange="changeQuantity(this.value,1);" />
```

when iI put in **Edit page -> Text** it works fine, but only when I click on **Visual** and go back in **Text** the code posted above become :

```
<input style="width: 10%; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #757575;" type="text" value="1" />
```

without the

```
onchange="changeQuantity(this.value,1);"
```

I can't understand why this happens..

Comment: I think this would help you understand better what's happening and maybe also resolve you issue https://www.godaddy.com/garage/webpro/wordpress/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/. Also  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333000/how-to-include-onclick-object-in-wordpress-html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828563/weird-thing-onclick-event-disappears-when-i-switch-the-visual-and-text-tab

Comment: can't solve.. @ionut

Comment: @AndreaLoda, please see my answer. I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read on this page, seems like you can install a plugin called [Raw HTML](https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/) which can help you in this situation. One guy [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/onclick-function-being-stripped-out-why-is-that/) says, and I quote:

> Now, from my understanding ( unless things have changed recently ) the default editor doesn’t allow any Javascript for security purposes which means that you will lose the onclick="".

So maybe you shouldn't use it.

If you still want to use it, after you install the plugin you can insert the code like this in the text tab, and it should work:

`[raw]<input style="width: 10%; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #757575;" type="text" value="1" onchange="changeQuantity(this.value,1);" />[/raw]`